# Can we project a 4D world using 3D video technology?

Tags: optics, spacetime-dimensions, geometry

Traditional movies, TV, etc, faithfully show our 3-dimensional world using 2 dimensions.  So can we have a movie that shows a 4-dimensional world using 3D technology?

Comment: If we could I'm not sure that our brains would be able to understand it.

Comment: see http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/8-cell.gif from the [wikipedia article on hypercube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube); there are some more animations and pictures on the [article on tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract)

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't be very enlightening.

Comment: I have to say that the ability to *"faithfully show our 3-dimensional world using 2 dimensions"* is not a feature of TV, but of your visual system which takes and interprets data in 2D it as a matter of course.

Comment: @Christoph yes I've seen those but they are hard to interpret because they are 2D representations of 4D objects.

Answer (score 1):

Not in any coherent sense. We are not built to comprehend the fourth physical dimensional. Any kind of television that would be able to project a truly 3D image would only be able to play 3 dimensional "shadows" of 4 dimensional objects like the hyper cube shown above. The hyper cube itself is a 3D shadow of a spinning 4 dimensional cube. A good way to think of it is imagining you had a glass cube and you spun it around continuously along an axis. The 2D shadow of the 3d cube on a near by flat surface, looks like two connected squares passing "through" each other. The shadow of the cube has unequal sides and angles where as the cube has of course equal sides at 90 degree angles. Likewise this is why the 3D image of a spinning hyper cube is two connected cubes passing through each other. The hyper cube in 4D also has all equal sides at right angles but this is lost in the 3D projection.